# finding specific customers in contract table

Tags: sql

I am working with MS SQL and need help creating a query.

I have a table called CustomerContracts, in it is multiple lines per item# for specific customers.

For example real data

```
item      cust_num
x      1156
x      3924
x      7565
x     84339
x    104365
x    106066
x    107377
x    118691
y      1156
y      3924
y      7565
y     84339
y    104365
y    106066
y    107377
```

So what I need to do is search the table by item number and a specific customer number and return the item if that customer number does not exist as a record for that item.

So, in this case I am checking all item records for the cust_num of 106066 and 118691 if the item does not contain both customers then I want it to be included in my results so in this cause item X would not show up, but item Y would.

I think I need to do some type of count.  I have tried using NOT IN(002,003) no luck.

Suggestions?

to satisfy my attempt at this.  I have tried at least 8 different ways, this is the latest attempt.

```
select 'Cust Does not exist' as Status,
    i.item as item,
    i.description as description,
    t.numcusts

From
    item i inner join (select count(cust_num) as numcusts,item
                        from itemcust
                        where cust_num NOT IN ('106066','118691')
                        group by item) t on t.item = i.item

where i.stat = 'A' and t.numcusts > 0
order by i.item,i.description
```

did not work.  So, I am still trying to resolve it.  I was able to develop a sort of solution using imbedded queries in Access, but can't get the sql it created to port over.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly you want? What parameters are you sending, and can you give an example of what you expect the result to be based on your example?

Comment: Do you also have a `Customer` table?

Comment: What is the expected behavior if for item y - cust_num 001 exists. What should be returned then?

Comment: I edited the original question with real data

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Show us what you've tried by updating your question with your code.

Comment: thank you for the edit carexcer

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have multiple records for a customer.  You want customers where the table has no record for a given item.  One approach is to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select cc.cust_num
from CustomerContracts cc
where c.cust_num in ('001', '002')
group by cc.cust_num
having sum(case when cc.cust_item_num in ('aaa') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Another approach is to use `not exists`:

```
select cc.*
from CustomerContract cc
where c.cust_num in ('001', '002') and
      not exists (select 1 from CustomerContracts where cust_item_num in ('aaa'));
```

The first gives a list of customer number.  The second gives all the records for those customers.

EDIT (based on edit to question):

The question is about items not customers.  A modification to the first approach will work.  If you only want items that have at least one of the customers, then use a `where` clause:

```
select cc.cust_item_num
from CustomerContracts cc
where c.cust_num in (106066, 118691)
group by cc.cust_item_num
having count(distinct c.cust_num) < 2;
```

If you want all items (even where neither customer appears), then count each customer match separately in the `having` clause:

```
select cc.cust_item_num
from CustomerContracts cc
group by cc.cust_item_num
having sum(case when c.cust_num = 106066 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when c.cust_num = 118691 then 1 else 0 en) = 0;
```

Comment: the cust_item_num is not unique and not part of what I am searching, my apologies if I didn't explain it right the first time.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but after 5 cups of coffee and 2 playlists I figured it out

```
select 'Cust Does not exist' as Status,
i.item as item,
i.description as description,expr1

From
item i RIGHT join (select itemcust.item,
sum(case when LTRIM(RTRIM(cust_num)) = '106066' or LTRIM(RTRIM(cust_num)) ='118691'then   1 else 0 end) as expr1
from itemcust
group by itemcust.item) t on t.item = i.item

where i.stat = 'A' AND expr1 <> 2
order by i.item,i.description
```

This gives me all the items that do not have both records or actually have them more than once.